# Can quantum mechanics and the fabric of spacetime be a viable defense to battery (or an offense that requires making contact)?

Tags: criminal-law

This might sound off, at first, but bear with me as I explain.

As a thought I have had for sometime, and then later brought to light by other people like in [this article](http://futurism.com/why-you-can-never-actually-touch-anything/), it is not possible to actually touch anything or anyone.

The sensation of touch is fulfilled essentially by electrons repelling where the waves pass through.

Given this is the case, there are many laws which do not have a clear definition of what touch actually consists of, instead focusing more on the action and implied state of matter making contact with matter (which is not possible) and what matter can be (an object, person, etc.).

Given that touch is not possible except under the theory of nuclear fusion where the state of an atom is fused with another atom both requiring an enormous amount of energy of an inconvenienced amount, and releasing under the theory, an unending source of energy, it is safe to say that this doesn't happen in (for example) a fist fight (even though the participants may feel like it had]).

In court, means, motive and opportunity must exist beyond a reasonable doubt. In a case involving a physical contact allegation, wouldn't quantum mechanics and spacetime eliminate the possibility of means?

Comment: You're defining *to touch* in an extremely restricted and non-commonsensical way, which is not at all related to the commonly understood way of defining it. Why do you think that would be an appropriate thing to do, when facing what are likely to be serious charges?

Comment: @Nij - the question relates to viability of defense from a logistical perspective. It is not an extremely restricted perspective. There is also no clear concept of 'common sense', however, defense does use sly methods to raise doubt on technicality frequently - how would this be any different to show that the entire concept itself defy laws that we are bound by without choice ?

Comment: @Nij - on the note of 'common sense', one might consider that the laws that govern our existence supersede those which we impose on ourselves.

Comment: "Common sense" is considered under the "reasonable person test", which has decades and tonnes of precedent in case law. Legal jurisdiction has never been bound by physical possibility.

Comment: Considering that humans have understood what a "touch" is for as long as we have existed, and we have only begun to understand what an atom is in the last 200 years or so, the unusual sense of "touch" meaning "atoms in contact" could not have influenced the common-law understanding of what a touch is. The recent discovery of how atoms interact doesn't have any impact on the long-established common law understanding of the action defined as a "touch".

Comment: @apsillers - where exactly is this defined ?   further, regarding using science in court to prove or disprove based on a change in our understanding or new technology, has been occurring for quite a long time, and there is plenty of case law where new scientific discoveries have set a precedent.

Comment: @Nij - if legal jurisdiction is not bound by physical possibility (example: the person was suffering from an advanced stage of ALS and in wheelchair bound, thus he was incapable physically to move across the city to where the alleged attack/theft/whatever occurred) - i guess under your rule, that guy would be going to jail even though physically, it was not possible - i would say that binds legal jurisdiction to physical possibility quite well.

Comment: @SamuelJackson Sure, science changes our understanding, so we now can define the age-old legal concept of a touch as something like "Achieving physical proximity sufficient to exert a force" or similar (I'm not a physicist). Many fundamental legal concepts (or concepts adjacent to law like this one) aren't defined anywhere definitely but exist through a shared understanding of how the concepts are treated in existing past case law.

Comment: Also, when you say that two atom touch during fusion, how do you understand what "to touch" even means? It is only by analogy to your own experience and observation of touch (or quantum-pseudo-touch, if you must) in the everyday physical world. Such an everyday experience of touch has alway been what the legal sense of "touch" refers to.

Comment: I edited this to clarify that you're interested in things like battery; let me know if you disagree with the edits.

Comment: This is such a frivolous and disingenuous line of reasoning that it doesn't even deserve a substantive response. An attorney who raised an argument like this one in a civil case would probably be sanctioned by the judge under Rule 11.

Comment: Amusing how simply because a concept is unpopular, it's automatic fuel for berating and social stigma -- the question is valid, clear, and represents a potential, yet it is down voted while snide comments are up voted ?  I didn't realize asking questions was a popularity contest of who can be the biggest wanker !  -- congratulations and I hope your few upvotes on a comment with intent to harm the author personally on a psychological factor. This response does not denote success, but more aptly to tell you how pathetic your lack of contribution has been.

Comment: My apologies if my comments read as snarky; they were an earnest attempt to demonstrate the fundamentals of definitions within common law (for example, prompting and answering your question about where "touch" is defined was an exchange that I really do hope expanded your understanding somewhat, and was not meant to attack or embarrass you). My latest comment, too, was aimed at demonstrating your existing understanding of what touch is in the day to day world in a way that aligns with the law's understanding, and persists even in light of your technical knowledge of touch on an atomic level.

Comment: I'll also add that I don't really think this deserve a down vote (certainly not 4) since its heart is the question of how law defines anything; a reasonable question. I must add, however, that the tone in which it is asked-- or at least the comments following -- feel somewhat as if you are trying to "prove the law wrong" somehow by making it reach an absurd conclusion, instead of making an earnest attempt at understanding how it actually works. Whether or not my reading is right, it may explain the downvotes.

Comment: @apsillers - Thank you for the clarification.  The premise behind this question is the 'new evidence' concept, where existing law lacks a clear definition of a term.  Usually, terminology and context are where law is contested given more specific technical knowledge or where the definition can be deemed as 'too vague' leaving reasonable doubt as to the terms intention, and subsequently, the term is updated and/or clearly defined as to the premise of it's intent.

Comment: @apsillers The comment which I found amusing was the one by ohwilleke which subsequently received 3 up-votes where it lacked any real contribution - and is self defined as such "it doesn't even deserve a substantive response".  Your statements were fine imho.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tl;dr**

No, it won't be a viable defense.

**Background**

*Touch has an established interpretation at common law.*

The common law is judge-made law.  If an offense involving touch existed at common law, then the meaning of touch is "defined" by the judicial opinions themselves.  As the comments have noted, you'll be able to find hundreds of years worth of opinions where judges have, by example, determined what qualifies as touching.  Putting your hand on someone, yes.  Spitting on someone, yes.  Blowing from a distance, no.  These examples make up the common law definition of touch.

But how, you may ask, would the common law evolve to include new information?  The answer is clear.  Say Jill purposely hits Jack in the face with a shovel.  When appearing before the judge, she says, "we have a new understanding of atomic proximity, so technically the atoms in the shovel never made contact with the atoms in Jack!"  The judge will say, "that's interesting, but it seems irrelevant to what we're trying to accomplish with the law: Jack still had to go to the hospital. Judgment for Jack."  Now the common law has incorporated the new information (...at Jill's expense).

*Touch isn't defined at the atomic level when interpreting a statute.*

Some offenses are defined, not by judges, but by statutes enacted by legislatures.  If the language in the statute is ambiguous, courts have to interpret its meaning.  This is often done by looking at the purpose of the statute or by looking at the plain meaning of the language.

*Statutory interpretation: purpose*

Where a court does not employ the plain meaning approach, it will often look for evidence of the drafter's intent.  In this case, the court would ask what the purpose of a law like battery is.  They'd probably conclude it has to do with preventing harm and offense.  In fact, they probably included things like that in the statute itself.  So they'd wonder if defining contact at an atomic level would help to prevent harm and offense; that seems unlikely.

In so doing, the court may analyze the legislative history.  It may look at events that happened around the time the law was enacted: did the legislature propose it because people were hitting each others' faces with shovels?  It might even appeal to the state of the common law at the time the statute was enacted for the proper definition.

*Statutory interpretation: plain meaning*

First, it might help to look at an example from District of Columbia v. Heller, 554 U.S. 570 (2008).  There the Court was tasked with interpreting some Second Amendment text.  In doing so it said, "we are guided by the principle that '[t]he Constitution was written to be understood by the voters; its words and phrases were used in their normal and ordinary as distinguished from technical meaning.' Normal meaning may of course include an idiomatic meaning, but it excludes secret or technical meanings." Id at 576-77.

Statutory interpretation also makes use of this plain meaning approach.  As stated by the Court, "where the language of an enactment is clear, and construction according to its terms does not lead to absurd or impracticable consequences, the words employed are to be taken as the final expression of the meaning intended.” United States v. Missouri Pacific R.R., 278 U.S. 269, 278 (1929); see also Black's Law Dictionary (10th ed. 2014).

This is bolstered by the practice of explicitly defining words with technical meanings in a definitions section of the statute.  For example, Article 9 of the Uniform Commercial Code employs a number of terms in a technical sense, and 9-102(a) defines 81 words that are intended to take on a technical meaning.

Another example is the Illinois battery statute, 720 ILCS 5:

> Sec. 12-3. Battery.
>      (a) A person commits battery if he or she knowingly without legal justification by any means (1) causes bodily harm to an individual or (2) makes physical contact of an insulting or provoking nature with an individual.

The statute doesn't have a technical definition for "physical contact."  So under plain meaning we'd construe it in its common sense.  Merriam-Webster's Dictionary (a favorite of U.S. courts) defines touch as, "to bring a bodily part into contact with especially so as to perceive through the tactile sense."  That definition implies that tactile sensation is what triggers (2), not any atomic concept of proximity.

If you're interested in further reading, proper interpretation of the term "physical contact" came up in the insurance contract setting in Mount Vernon Fire Ins. Co. v. Busby, 219 Cal. App. 4th 876 (2013).

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

Comment: Thank you Pat.  I guess what I am curious about is when there is no clear definition.  Yes, convictions have likely been applied under the assumption , however I have been unable to locate (going way back even) law where 'touch' or 'contact' is clearly defined where usually the terms are defined to prevent them from being used differently as language evolves in the future.

Comment: @SamuelJackson You almost have to think of the common law way of getting at a definition as machine learning rather than axiomatic.